# Angularjs: how to properly save a blob pdf file recieved from the server

Tags: angularjs, pdf

The recieved file goes through `$http` and i need to save the response data into a file, i am using `angular-file-saver`, the recieved files are pdf docx, but viewing the saved pdf file shows nothing on the reader, while other downloaders like `PostMan` does save it right.

the function that takes care of saving has this code:

```
function saveFile(data, header){
    var extensions = {
        "application/pdf": ".pdf",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document": ".docx"
    }

    var file = new Blob([data], {type: header});

    FileSaver.saveAs(file, documentsShow.document.name + extensions[header]);
}
```

`data` is the body data retrieved from `$http` success and `header` is the `Content-Type` also recieved from `$http` response

in case if it's needed, the `$http` code is like this:

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    data: data,    //This is sometimes null but it's not relevant for the application
    url: "path/to/download"
}).then(function(data){
    saveFile(data.data, data.header("Content-Type"));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main problem I see here is that Angular will still be trying to parse the response as JSON.

You can modify this so it resolves with a `Blob` object

```
$http.get('path/to/download', {
    responseType: 'blob'
}).then(function(res) {
    FileSaver.saveAs(res.data, ...)
});
```

---

FYI, `data` is not used in `GET` requests.